# Why does compiler think I am using double, in "pow". 'double' to 'float' C4244

Tags: c, double

I am new to C programming. I keep getting this error, (in this case relating to code inside the cubic root function):

> 1>c:\users\r\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab5.c\lab5.c\lab5code.c(57): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data

I have tried storing the cubic root calculation in a float, and then returning that to main, but still no luck. I have seen people compile my code with no problems.
I have so far tested the code on VS 2008, and 2010 express editions, same errors. I get this a lot, trying to figure out why.

```
   //INCLUDE HEADER FILES
#include <stdio.h> //Defines printf, scanf & getch
#include <conio.h> //Defines get.ch
#include <stdlib.h> //Defines system("pause")
#include <math.h> //Defines math functions


// FUNCTION PROTOTYPES
void explain();
float get_value();
float cubic_root(float num);
void display(float x, float y); 

int main(void) 
{
    float in,out;
    //Variable Declarations 
    explain();          //Explain
    in=get_value();     //Get Value from USER
    out=cubic_root(in); //Calculations
    display(in,out);    //Output
}

//FUNCTION DEFINITIONS 
void explain(void)
{
    system("cls");
    puts("This will take cubic root\nPress enter to continue...");
    _getch();

}

float get_value(void)
{
    float input;
    fflush(stdin);
    puts("Enter the number you want to cube root...\n");
    scanf_s("%f",&input);
    return(input);
}

float cubic_root(float num)
{
    float div,total;
    total=(pow(num,1.0/3.0));
    return(total);

}

void display(float x, float y)
{
    printf("%.1f, %.1f",x,y);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: 0.33 is far from accurate compared to 1.0/3 or 1.0f/3

Comment: Get a real compiler. Something like your `float explain()` is not anywhere near conforming C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
exp1 = pow(num, 0.33);
```

assigns the return value of [the `pow()` function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pow), which has type `double`, to `exp` which has type `float`.

The fix is to use the `powf()` function instead:

```
float cubic_root(float num)
{
    return powf(num, 1.f / 3.f);
}
```

You can of course just cast the result to `float` to tell the compiler you really mean this, but it seems extremely wasteful and pointless to do the exponentiation calculation using more precision than you really need, so don't do that.

Comment: Indeed the best answer **but** the return value will be incorrect. See for yourself by testing cubic_root by multiplying the answer by itself 3 times and see how deviant you are from the input.

Comment: @Bathsheba, I am using 1.0/3.0, I know that .33 would not be correct.

Comment: @Bathsheba Good point, I improved the precision of the 1/3 constant, I think it helped. For e.g. `cubic_root(8)` I got `2.000000` on ideone.

Comment: Formatted to 6 digits after decimal place, for input of `1337.04`, I got the output `11.016614`. That is the exact value.

Answer (score 3):

Because `pow()` returns a `double`, and you are assigning it to a `float`.

```
exp1=pow(num,0.33);
```

Comment: Okay, so how do I convert the double to a float. OR, do I not use the pow if I am trying to stick to float for now?

Comment: @Typical Use a different type, different function: powf(), or cast the result.

Comment: @Typical Why do you want to use `float`? They don't give you many significant digits. A $2 calculator will give you better than a C float! See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) for details.

Comment: @PM2Ring Why do you assume that high accuracy is needed?

Comment: @2501 : I don't make that assumption; I was merely pointing out that float is rather limited in its precision. But I am curious to know why Typical is so keen to use them in this day & age.

Comment: Hah! I am not using them out of love. In my college it is what the prof. tells us to use at this point.

Comment: @Typical : Oh dear. Maybe you should gently inform the professor that the PDP 11 is no longer state of the art technology. :) FWIW, I think the last time I used floats in C was back in the late 1980s on my trusty old Amiga 2000 that had 10 MB of RAM, which was a _lot_ of RAM in those days (those chips were worth $100 / MB).

Comment: I guess floats are ok if you don't need double (or long double) precision and you need to work with a really big array of them. In the old days, floats were faster than doubles, but I doubt that applies today, except maybe on some embedded devices. Modern FP hardware tends to use fairly high precision internally and converting back & forth between that internal format and other formats (whether double or float) incurs a small time penalty.

Answer (score 3):

`pow()` returns a `double` and you're converting it to a `float`. That's why a warning is emitted and you should take notice of it.

The best thing to do is to refactor your code to use `double` precision variables. You will probably find that there is no performance hit in doing that as many low level floating point computations are at (or higher than) double precision anyway.

Note that `pow(num, 0.33);` is a grotesque approximation for a cube root. Use `pow(num, 1.0 / 3);` instead. You need to use `1.0` so the literal is evaluated (most likely at compile time) in floating point.